# Python global not updating in new object instance

Tags: python, class, object, global-variables

I have a Python file with a global var and define a class:

```
ROOT = 'https://api.example.com/2.0/'

class Mail(object):
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.name = "FName"

        if api_key.find('-'):
            dc = api_key.split('-')[1]

        global ROOT
        print "initing root to: %s" % (ROOT,)
        ROOT = ROOT.replace('https://api.', 'https://'+dc+'.api.')
        print "initing after replace of ROOT: %s" % (ROOT,)

    def pprint(self):
        print 'POST to %s' % (ROOT,)
```

It seems that the `ROOT` global is not updated once it's set:

```
>>> import pyglob 
>>> mc = pyglob.Mail('dfadsfad-us1')
initing root to: https://api.example.com/2.0/
initing after replace of ROOT: https://us1.api.example.com/2.0/
>>> mc.pprint()
POST to https://us1.api.example.com/2.0/
>>> mc3 = pyglob.Mail('dfadsfad-us3')
initing root to: https://us1.api.example.com/2.0/
initing after replace of ROOT: https://us1.api.example.com/2.0/
>>> mc3.pprint()
POST to https://us1.api.example.com/2.0/
>>> mc.pprint()
POST to https://us1.api.example.com/2.0/
```

Can someone explain how this works and why it happens?

Comment: Because after the first replace call there's no `'https://api.'` to replace.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, ahhh! Didn't see that coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've made `ROOT = https://us1.api.example.com/2.0/`, `ROOT.replace('https://api.', 'https://'+dc+'.api.')` doesn't do anything, since `'https://api.'` is no longer in `ROOT`--you've replaced it.

This whole situation looks extremely messy and you probably want to refactor this not to rebind globals at all.

Comment: Cool. But it's safe to say that even if the `replace` is fixed, sharing a global var could cause conflicts when there's more than one instance of the class, right?

Comment: Yes. If you want something for the instance, make it an attribute of `self`.